# Python urllib open issue

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to fetch data from **http://book.libertorrent.com/**, but at the moment I'm failing badly because some additional data (headers) present in response. My code is very simple:

```
response = urllib.urlopen('http://book.libertorrent.com/login.php')
f = open('someFile.html', 'w')
f.write(response.read())
```

**read()** returns:

```
Date: Fri, 09 Nov 2012 07:36:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, pre-check=0, post-check=0
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: bb_test=973132321; path=/; domain=book.libertorrent.com
Content-Language: ru

1ec0
...Html...
0
```

And **response.info()** is empty.

is there any way to correct response?

Comment: After response.read(), what does response.getcode() says? On my Mac, response.read() returns the html, while .getcode() returns 200, which is OK (success).

Comment: Your approach generally works; I'm getting the same problems you are when I try it with that website...

Comment: Me too, interestingly it works with Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
$ echo -ne "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: book.libertorrent.com\r\n\r\n" | nc book.libertorrent.com 80 | head -n 10
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
WWW
Date: Sat, 10 Nov 2012 17:41:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: ru

1f57
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html dir="ltr">
```

See that "WWW" in the second line? That's no valid HTTP header, I'm guessing that's what's throwing off the response parser here.

By the way, python2 and python3 behave differently here:

- python2 seems to immediately interpret anything after this invalid header as content
- python3 ignores all headers and continues reading the content after the double newline. Because the headers are ignored, so is the transfer encoding, and therfore the content lengths are interpreted as part of the body.

So in the end the problem is that the server is sending an invalid response, which should be fixed at the server's end.

Comment: I try this code on Python3, results are better than Python2, headers exists in info(). Now response look like: 1ec0
...Html...
0